# Static method with generic return type

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to define a static method which can return childs of a specific class. I am using generics for that it is not working.

Example code:

```
public class Test {

    class A {
    }

    class B extends A {
    }

    public static <T extends A> T getA() {
        return new B();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = getA();
    }
}
```

As you can see I am saying `getA()` will return T which is a child of the "A" class. I return B instance there, and it is a child of A but still it is not compiling. Any idea about what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Edit: And there would be multiple sub types to return from `getA()`

```
public class Test {

    class A {
    }

    class B extends A {
    }

    class C extends A {
    }

    public static <T extends A> T getA(int type) {
        if(type = 0) {
             return new B();
        } else {
             return new C();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = getA(0);
        C c = getA(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static <T extends A> T getA(Class<T> type) { return type.cast(new B());  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see I am saying `getA()` will return T which is a child of the "A" class.

Yes, but you're allowing the caller to say *which* child class of `A` they want to have returned.

What if you wrote `X x = getA();`, where `X` is a subtype of `A` but not `B`?

The only thing you can safely return from that method is `null`.

If you want to say the method will return *any* subtype of `A`, make the return type `A`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you saying it is a bad practice? I just don't want cast to B every time in main method. And also there will other subclasses to return. You can see it my edit.

Comment: If you are always going to return a B, make the return type B.

Comment: In terms of whether it's "bad practice": no, it's that you are misunderstanding the semantics of the options. `<T extends A> T` says to the caller "I'll return a thing with type of your choice"; `A` says to the caller "I'll return a thing which is some subtype of A (I'll choose which, and I can change my mind if I like)"; `B` is essentially that same as `A`, just a bit more specific as to which subtypes of A could be returned.